# Regex for address

Tags: javascript, regex

With some addresses a building might take up multiple door numbers for example 13 - 15 StreetName.
The "13 - 15" is the part I am focusing on. How would you do a regular expression to pick out this part.

I thought something like [0-9] - [0-9] which works for 1 - 3 but if the address was 12 - 13 [0-9][0-9] - [0-9][0-9] could work but then I want to make sure that something like 13 - 3 wouldnt work as the addresses cannot go backwards and something like 99 - 103 would also work where the numbers are different lengths. Is it really simple and I'm missing something?

I'm still a student and not very good at regular expressions, I just need it for some js I'm doing and have spent far too long getting nowhere.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure what this has to do with addresses, as it just looks like you're dealing with two simple numbers. Regex doesn't do math, so trying to make a pattern that ensures the first number is smaller than the second number will be an exercise in futility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not really a good way to do this since you're effectively trying to parse something that is not a [regular language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language). Referencing something that you've seen before is allowed by several regular expression languages though, but that won't help you in this specific case.

We can easily go for the brute-force solution though :)

https://regex101.com/r/4bRmiL/1

```
^(\d{3} - \d{3,}|\d{2} - \d{2,}|\d - \d+)$
```

As you can see though, it still breaks for cases like `5 - 1` which are probably invalid. That's something you need to check outside of the regex.

Comment: Fair point and yeah the 5 - 1 would be invalid. I might just hardcode it rather than do this whole regex stuff. Was hoping to get it all done in a clean 1 line but I don't see that happening.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is even possible with regex.  I would instead just do something like this:

```js
var addresses = [
    "12 - 14 State St.",
    "14 - 12 State St.",
];

addresses.forEach(address => console.log(validAddress(address)));

function validAddress(address) {
    return !!(address.match(/\d+\s?-\s?\d+/) || []).filter(a => {
        var numbers = a.split('-').map(b => b.trim());
        return (numbers.length && numbers[0] < numbers[1]);
    }).length;
}
```